# What is the difference between char in a function and outside a function?

Tags: c, buffer-overflow

Ive got 2 example codes, one is safe against buffer overflows even compiled with
`gcc -fno-stack-protector -fno-pie -m32 save.c -o save`

Code of safe program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char check[16];

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    printf("Enter a string: ");
    gets(check);
    printf("%s\n", check);
    printf("Accepted.\n");

}
```

Code of unsafe (vulnerable) program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char check[16];
    printf("Enter a string: ");
    gets(check);
    printf("%s\n", check);
    printf("Accepted.\n");

}
```

Why is the char outside the program "safe"? (in my case)

Comment: Neither programs are safe, because `gets` is an unsafe function.

Comment: Please, make an effort to fix your spelling mistakes. You wrote "save" instead of "safe" several times. It makes it very hard to read.

Comment: @MicheleDorigatti They're not a native English speaker, give them a break.

Comment: Yeah i know, but i cant explain whats the difference...

Comment: Why do you think there's a difference in terms of the safety?

Comment: `gets` is a [dangerous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used) function that have been removed from the C specification.

Comment: @Barmar because overflowing the buffer doesnt work in the first case. And sorry for my writing mistakes.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I posted that comment earlier, but I believe he's using it deliberately to cause a buffer overflow.

Comment: @BitFriends What do you mean "doesn't work"? It causes undefined behavior, so anything can happen. It might appear to work, it might cause a segmentation error, something else could happen.

Comment: @Barmar the first one exited completely clean even with overflowing the check char. I ran it with ```strace``` and ```gdb```. Nothing.

Comment: Did you try `valgrind`?

Comment: @BitFriends Undefined behavior doesn't always cause an error.

Comment: @Barmar that could be possible. Bunt im just wondering, why those 2 programs acting so "much" different

Comment: Because smashing the stack is different from smashing the data segment.

Comment: It's really unclear what you're asking. The arrays in the two versions are susceptible to overflow by gets() so both are unsafe. Voting to close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case you're declaring a global variable. This is generally a bad habit to get into for a multitude of reasons, many of which you'll discover over time, so it's best to never do that unless you have no other option.

The second case makes it local to `main()`.

Even better is to make a function that performs the get-assign operation and returns `char*`.

It's worth noting that in both cases **nothing about this program is safe** as you're using a comically tiny buffer (16 bytes!) and never use a function that's buffer-length limited. `gets` is one of the worst to use. Consider something else, anything else, even `scanf('%15s', &check)`.

Moving the buffer from one location to another doesn't make it any safer. The problem is with the buffer and how it's used.

Comment: You're answering the question in the title, not the question in the text.

Comment: @Barmar This question is like an onion with layers, apparently.

Comment: @Barmar: "Question body" or simply "body" is more descriptive than "text" in this case.